# moving the subquery to the where or from clause, since I don't need it's values

Tags: mysql

Right now my sql query gives back a valid array of id's and distance pairs.
I want to change my query to just give back id's. Not sure how to rearrange the subquery in my query.

```
SELECT distinct t2.id, ( 5 * distance_given1 ) AS distance_calculated 
FROM table1 t1 
inner join table2 t2 on t1.id = t2.m_id
HAVING distance_calculated < distance_given2 
ORDER BY distance_calculated LIMIT 0 , 20
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just move the expression into the `WHERE` clause.

```
SELECT DISTINCT t2.id
FROM table1 t1
INNER JION table2 t2 ON t1.id = t2.m_id
WHERE (5 * distance_given1) < distance_given2
ORDER BY (5 * distance_given1)
LIMIT 0, 20
```

If the expression is more complicated and you don't want to repeat it, you can use a subquery:

```
SELECT id 
FROM (SELECT distinct t2.id, ( 5 * distance_given1 ) AS distance_calculated 
      FROM table1 t1 
      inner join table2 t2 on t1.id = t2.m_id
      HAVING distance_calculated < distance_given2
      ORDER BY distance_calculated
      LIMIT 0 , 20) AS x
```

Comment: close, but the order is by distance_calculated, not distance_gven. Updated question to be more clear

Comment: @airnet: `order by X` and `order by 5*X` - do you think that would result in different ordering?

Comment: i have to use distance_calcuated in the ORDER By clause as well.

Comment: Multiplying numbers by a positive number doesn't change their order. If `x < y` then `5x < 5y`. This is simple algebra.

Comment: Well, I simplified my question for Stackoverflow, So I want to know how to referrence the subquery later on while specifying it in the WHERE clause.

Comment: OK, I've changed my answer to repeat the expression.

Comment: And added another version that simply puts the original query in a subquery, so you can just return the ID without the distance column.